# Facebook android code not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

i'm trying to get the user details on facebook android sdk..

i'm not getting results from `Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()` which is an updated function from android sdk manager

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private TextView userInfoTextView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.authButton);

        authButton.setFragment(this);
        authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location",
                "user_birthday", "user_likes"));
        userInfoTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userInfoTextView);

        return view;
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generatedation I put the tags below in wrong
                    // places (I method stub
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Display the parsed user info
                        Toast.makeText(null, "Entered the user section",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        userInfoTextView.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(user));
                    } else if (user == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(null, "User is null error in request",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }
            }).executeAsync();

            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            userInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        }
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {
        StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");

        userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n", user.getName()));
        userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", user.getBirthday()));
        userInfo.append(String.format("Location: %s\n\n", user.getLocation()
                .getProperty("name")));
        userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n",
                user.getProperty("locale")));
        // JSONArray languages = (JSONArray)user.getProperty("languages");
        GraphObjectList<MyGraphLanguage> languages = (user
                .cast(MyGraphUser.class)).getLanguages();
        if (languages.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> languageNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (MyGraphLanguage language : languages) {
                languageNames.add(language.getName());
            }
            userInfo.append(String.format("Languages: %s\n\n",
                    languageNames.toString()));
        }

        return userInfo.toString();
    }

    private interface MyGraphLanguage extends GraphObject {
        // Getter for the ID field
        String getId();

        // Getter for the Name field
        String getName();
    }

    private interface MyGraphUser extends GraphUser {
        // Create a setter to enable easy extraction of the languages field
        GraphObjectList<MyGraphLanguage> getLanguages();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with simple following code.

```
public class Profile_Detail extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    ImageView profile_pic;

    TextView mfirstname, mlastname, mfullname, mfacebookLink, mfacebookId,
            mfacebookUnm, mgender, mEmail;

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback,
                        savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                        .setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

        profile_pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        mfirstname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mlastname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        mfullname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        mfacebookLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        mfacebookId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        mfacebookUnm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        mgender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        mEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    // make request to the /me API
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {
                                         mfirstname.setText(user.getFirstName());
                                         mlastname.setText(user.getLastName());
                                         mfullname.setText(user.getName());
                                         mfacebookLink.setText(user.getLink());
                                        mfacebookId.setText(user.getId());
                                        mfacebookUnm.setText(user.getUsername()
                                                + " (" + user.getName() + ")");
                                        String gender = user.asMap()
                                                .get("gender").toString();
                                        String email = user.asMap()
                                                .get("email").toString();
                                        mgender.setText(gender);
                                        mEmail.setText(email);

                                        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                                                .permitAll().build();
                                        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                                        try {
                                            URL image_value = new URL(
                                                    "http://graph.facebook.com/"
                                                            + user.getId()
                                                            + "/picture?type=large");
                                            Bitmap bmp = null;
                                            try {
                                                bmp = BitmapFactory
                                                        .decodeStream(image_value
                                                                .openConnection()
                                                                .getInputStream());
                                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                            profile_pic.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error...",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

        }
    }
}
```

With this above code i am successfully able to get the detail of facebook user as well as profile picture.